# Spring Data PagedListHolder second page is show the same data as first page when the page size is greater than or equal the data size

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I've the actual data = 25 records and then I sent the request

> Page : 1
> PageSize : 25

The data return with 25 records correctly but when I try

> Page : 2
> PageSize : 25

The data return with 25 records same way as Page 1 why the data is not ending on the first page ?
Could you please help me to fix this with any input ?
How can I get correct data on the page for any input?
Here is my code :

```
PagedListHolder<ObjectResponseDTO> pagedListHolder = new PagedListHolder<>(ObjectResponse);
pagedListHolder.setPage(Request.getPageDesc().getCurrentPage() - 1);
pagedListHolder.setPageSize(Request.getPageDesc().getPageSize());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PagedListHolder` is stateful and is on page `Request.getPageDesc().getCurrentPage() - 1`.

You need to use the `pagedListHolder.nextPage();` method to change the page number status.